# Select all preceding column values of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Product as

```
Start    End
 A        M
 M        T
 T        F
```

I need to get all preceding values of the input value. For example, if input is T, the query should return A, M. If input is M, it should return A. For F, the output should be A, M, T. I have tried self join but could not get the result.

Comment: *Preceding* implies a row order. There is no field in your table that could be used to specify order.

Comment: You're not tempted to switch to nested sets?

Comment: @giorgosbestos that's simply incorrect. This is a simple adjacency list

Comment: @Strawberry You cannot solve this in MySQL, unless you have a field specifying consecutive rows.

Comment: One row's End value is equal to next row's Start value. Can that be used ?

Comment: @giorgosbetsos maybe you can't , but I can

Comment: @John  You need  a recursive query to consume this kind of information. Up to version 5.7 no such feature is supported. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @giorgosbetsos now you're making sense ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of an answer, but too long for a comment...

(MySQL 8.0 aside) there's no recursion built in to MySQL. Instead, options include:

- joining the table to itself as often as could possibly be required
- switching to another model (e.g. [Nested Set](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/))
- handling the recursion at the application level (e.g. with a bit of PHP)

Here's an example of the first option:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/355414/4

Answer (score 0):

you could add order column to identify the preceding columns. e.g `primary key` like id will work also. After that you can execute query like

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(start) preceding_val FROM table_name WHERE id < (SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE end=your_value)
```

this will give you a row with all the preceding start value comma separated for your given end value.

Comment: I need to do it without using order column like id

Comment: Is your start and end values are always alphabetically ordered ? like if M is start then end value would be after M alphabet ?